# Which is correct, "differently than" or "differently from", or neither?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-request

Which is correct, "sort compares strings differently from awk", or "sort compares strings differently than awk", or both are bad, and I should rephrase it?

Comment: It might help for you to define "sort", "string", and "awk" for those of us less programming savy

Comment: "Sort compares strings differently from how Awk does it."

Comment: @katatahito `sort` is a UNIX command line program that, unsurprisingly sorts the lines in its input.  `AWK` is a UNIX command line program that processes "AWK programs" which also support sorting of lines of text, but the output of the two programs will differ; because, they don't share the exact same rules on ordering the lines of input.

Comment: When comparing how one thing does something compared to another, always use "Than"

Answer (score 2):

Neither wording is wrong. But, according to [Google Books Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=differently%20from%2Cdifferently%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifferently%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferently%20than%3B%2Cc0), *differently from* is more common than *differently than*—at least in writing.

[image: differently from or differently than]

Answer (score 2):

> sort compares strings differently from awk

This phrase carries extra meanings beyond the differences in how the command `sort` and the command `awk` handle strings.  It can also mean that `sort` compares strings differently when received from the output of `awk`.  I would avoid it for that reason.

> sort compares strings differently than awk

This phrase is more limited, because now the comment cannot be possibly misread as a comment based on how sort behaves based on the origin of the strings.

> sort and awk compare strings differently

Would be clear and to the point, avoiding the anchoring of one command and the comparison to another by simply stating they function differently.

I would suggest "differently than" because it doesn't imply a source of the input, or simply rearrange the sentence to not have one an indirect object.

Answer (score -1):

I was taught that, "differently than" is incorrect. "Different" is not a comparative adjective, and so "differently" is not a comparative adverb.

Something is either "different" or "not different" when you place it next to something else. There may be *degrees* of difference, and in that case "than" may be appropriate, for example, if you were trying to *express* that degree: "A is more different than B is (from something else)".

If it is "different", then that "difference" separates it away "from" the thing it is compared with. It "differs from" it.

"Different than" is, however, in popular usage because of poor grammar teaching and the fact that people have been learning by incorrect example. Hence, because it is widely prevalent, it is becoming accepted.

The choice is yours: to use "from" and be correct, and sound well-educated; or to use "than", and sound like a poorly-educated but contemporary native of an English-speaking country.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why this is so hard to understand. I go **to** a place a place, and come **from** a place. Just like go and come are antonyms, different and similar are antonyms. Likewise, an object is similar **to** another or different **from** it. Different than makes no sense, at all.

**Than** is used with there is a degree of comparison, e.g. better than, more than, less than, further than, closer than etc.

Comment: That seems to contradict previous answers. Can you provide a source which confirms that differently than is wrong?

Comment: -1 to this answer. "I am not sure why this is so hard to understand" is offensive.  It assumes that before posting the answer, you (or somebody else) wrote something, I read it, was unable to undestand, and now I am asking the same question again.  Which is not the case.

Answer (score -2):

Both are correct.

Let me explain, differently than: it is here used as an adjective in comparative degree like probably, instantly.

Differently from: it is used as an attribute like both the players play football but one is differently played from another.